# How can I load images one after another?

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing

I have a website with a lot of images in it. I want some images load before another (because user will scroll to the last images). Let's say this is html:

```
<img src='img1.jpg'>
<img src='img2.jpg'>
<img src='img3.jpg'>
<img src='img4.jpg'>
```

How can I make `img3.jpg` and `img4.jpg` start to load after `img1.jpg` and `img2.jpg` loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with Steve Testa's answer - Mike Tupola's jQuery plugin is one of the best for so-called "Lazy Loading" - however, I recently stumbled upon a major improvement to the plugin. As Steve mentioned, Mike Tupola's plugin only works with images; fortunately, this plugin is called LazyLoadAny - which allows you to lazy load just about anything you want: https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any

I recently used this on a product listing page where the client didn't pagination but didn't want them all to load immediately - its a great resource and easy to use. If you need further explanation just ask.

Answer (score 1):

quick google search (http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script3.htm, page has example) provides a function to load another image after a previous image has finished loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadingImage = false;

function LoadImage(imageName,imageFile)
{
  if ((!document.images) || loadingImage) return;
  loadingImage = true;

  if (document.images[imageName].src.indexOf(imageFile)<0)
  {
    document.images[imageName].src = imageFile;
  }
  loadingImage = false;
}
LoadImage('image0','number0.gif');
</script>
```

then use like

```
<img name="image0" onLoad="LoadImage('image1','number1.gif')">
<img name="image1" onLoad="LoadImage('image2','number2.gif')">
```

...and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a more lightweight plugin which loads images without the [overhead of jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

The [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/) library provides auto-lazy loading of images:

**1.** Define your placeholders:

```html
<span data-src="img1" data-alt="some alt text 1"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>

<span data-src="img2" data-alt="some alt text 2"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>
```

**2.** Initialize lazy loading via javascript:

```js
Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder");
```

The plugin will load the images when they get visible for the user. If they should load earlier, you can provide a threshold:

```js
Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder", {
    threshold: 200
});
```

Now the specific image will be loaded 200 pixels before it gets visible in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need to force a lazy load scenario with javascript. I personally am a big fan of [Mike Tupola's jquery plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload). It will only load images if they're visible. That way if the user never scrolls down any images that aren't visible will never load.